# Link between eigenvalues of a symmetric matrix and a functional space

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, linear-algebra, measure-theory, eigenvalues

Let $f_1,\dots,f_n \in L^2(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$ be $n$ mutually orthogonal functions with $\int f^2_i =1$ such that $|\{x \in \mathbb{R} | f_i(x) = 0\}| = 0$ for any $i \in \{1, \dots,n\}$. Does there exist $g \in L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$ such that all the eigenvalues of the real symmetric matrix $M = \left( \int_{\mathbb{R}} g f_i f_j\right)_{i,j}$ are different ?

---

The condition that the nodal sets have zero measure gives a lot of freedom to make $M$ vary. For instance we can easily build a $g$ such that all the non-diagonal elements are different to zero, but this is not enough for all the eigenvalues to be different. Actually the statement must be true generically (in the sense that for any starting $g$ for which it's wrong, there exists a perturbation of $g$ such that this becomes true) and it would be even better if one manages to find a proof of it, but I need only the existence of one such $g$ to begin.

Comment: Perhaps you want to assume the $f_i$ are not just different but linearly independent?  Otherwise, they could all be different scalar multiples of the same function, in which case your matrix has rank $1$ and the eigenvalue $0$ has multiplicity $n-1$.

Comment: Yes indeed, I normalized them so that they are linearly independent

Comment: Normalizing does not make them linearly independent.

Comment: Ok they are orthogonal actually in my problem so now they are linearly independent :p